# How to pass data from blade.php file to a react component using HTML element attributes?

Tags: javascript, php, reactjs, laravel, laravel-6

HELP! I'm doing React + Laravel 6.
I want to pass a string to my props in my React component but this has to be passed/written from a file.blade.php file.

** file.blade.php **

`<div id="MyComponent"></div>`

`<div id="MyComponent"> string I want to pass</div>` I can't get this innerHTML as well as ID is already tagged.

`<div id="MyComponent" customProp="string to I want to pass"></div>` I'm not sure if it is possible to use a custom property or the native property of an HTML tag and fetch it inside the JS component but I know this is possible for React components.

I know that php files can't type `<MyComponent />` inside a blade.php file like I can in JS and php files can only use a component through ID tag. Please don't suggest `fetch`, i know that it would solve this problem but the process is needlessly longer for the desired effect, just for display.I'd rather hard code this component in HTML.

Desired effect: I want this React Component to adjust it's text based on the passed string. I can simply hard code the text inside JS but component wouldn't be reusable and defeat the componentization.

Answer (score 1):

You can define your `element` first as a const/var or whatever. Then you access the element's attributes with `element.attributes` and iterate through your attributes like so:

```
const element = document.getElementById('MyComponent');

ReactDOM.render(
    <MyComponent {...element.attributes} />,
    element
);
```

You can access the attributes with `this.props`.

If you're passing data-* attributes your can pass those with `{...element.dataset}`

Comment: the dataset is gold

Answer (score 0):

you can use `<MyComponent />`

```php
<div id="app">
     <MyComponent customProp="string to I want to pass" />
</div>
```

in app.js

```js
 ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

Comment: But I need to type in the attribute in HTML like 
``` <div id="MyComponent" customProp="My Message"> </div> ```
in a php file. Not in .js file so the <MyComponent /> won't work inside .php file.

Comment: yes u can do that once app components Mount inside id="app" then u can include other components inside that

Answer (score 0):

I am not a hardcore reactjs dev but what I did recently for a tool I built with a reactjs dev was pass in my variable as a data attribute like so:

```
<div id="root" data-text="blah blah">
```

And then, looking at his source code, I can see a function:

```
componentDidMount()
{
      //other variables here 
      let data_text= $('#root').attr("data-text"); //get the data attribute variable
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Holy! It worked. The .attr is new to me. I haven't really explored jQuery. I wish I've read this yesterday.

Comment: Glad it helped @shupesmerga 

Comment: This would work, but you already access the element when doing ReactDOM.render(etc.);
You can pass the attributes within the ReactDOM.render() function immediately